# Как сделать сортировку Фамилий по алфавиту в односвязном списке? C++/CLI

Tags: сортировка, c++-cli, односвязный-список

```
value struct State          
{
  String^ surname;      // Фамилия
  String^ initials;     // Имя и отчество
  String^ room;         //категория номера
  String^ settlement;       // дата заселения
  float sum;                // Сумма счета
  State^ next;          // указатель на следующий узел
};
typedef State^ P_State;     // Объявление указателя на структуру
```

Comment: текстовую информацию приводите текстом, а не изображениями

Comment: и то что у вас на изображение - это не с++

Comment: это часть кода структуры на c++

Comment: Это структура ссылочного типа

Comment: то что у вас на скрине - это не с++, подобный синтаксис недопустим в с++

Comment: Это проект Windows Form c++

Comment: в таком случае метку измените с `с++` на `winforms`

Comment: Код, который вы привели, - на языке C++/CLI. Это не C++! Это два **разных** языка.

Comment: Прошу прощения за мою не осведомленность. Спасибо что поправили, вы можете помочь с сортировкой?

Comment: Если вас в учебном заведении заставляют учить C++/CLI, то передайте преподу мои слова: $@#%! (в общем, забанят меня за них). Если вы сами за него взялись, то бросайте. Сперва учите нормальный C++ и C#, а уже посли них, беритесь за этот (тогда вы точно будете знать, нужен ли он вам).

Comment: Не нужна здесь метка WinForms. Вопрос никак не связан с GUI.

Comment: Удалите картинку. Опубликуйте код в виде текста.

Comment: Очистите код от ненужных инклюдов.

Comment: Да, задание из учебного заведения , и это задание курсовой , даже передав ваши слова ничего не изменю с учебной программой о чём вы и сами знаете

Comment: надеюсь правильно исправил, теперь кто-то может помочь с моим вопросом?